# Measure in Power BI using if statements

Tags: conditional-statements, powerbi, measure

I want to create a the following measure using if statement:

```
PRE_MTD_M_visit_cost_v2 =
    if('table_1'[Source_Type]="Online";
        CALCULATE((DIVIDE(21*[MTD_M_visit_cost];7)));
        'table_1'[M_visit_cost])
```

I want to create a measure with a conditional statement if column `Source_Type` has “Online” then I want to calculate `MTD_M_visit_cost` based on the number of passed working days in April (which has 21 working days).
If column Source_Type has another text value, I want to return `M_visit_cost` measure (which I already have created).

PBI returns the following error:

> It is impossible to define one value for the "Source_Type" column in
>   the "roistat-analytics-data" table. This can happen if, for a single
>   result, a measure formula refers to a column containing a set of
>   values, without specifying an aggregate, for example MIN, MAX, COUNT,
>   or SUM.

I know that I can create a conditional column, but ideally, it would be great to be able to create a measure.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible, as long as the aggregation of both 'sub-measures' is the same. You can access the values in a row by using the nameX (sumX, avarageX) functions. These functions iterates over a row, so you can make different calculation based on the values in the specific row.

Since you've not provided sample data, I've built a small sample. Hope this is something you can work with. In my example "Sales", I only want to add the VAT to the Amount, if the Sales Type = "Online". For Offline, the VAT will be ignored.

```
 SalesAmount = 
    SUMX( Sales;
    IF ( Sales[Type] = "Online" ; Sales[Amount] + Sales[VAT] ; Sales[Amount] 
    )
 )
```

Based on your formula, it will be something like this:

```
PRE_MTD_M_visit_cost_v2 =
    SUMX (
        table_1;
        IF (
            'table_1'[Source_Type] = "Online";
            DIVIDE ( 21 * [MTD_M_visit_cost]; 7 );
           'table_1'[M_visit_cost]
        )
    )
```

My sample:

[image: Sample]